# Delphi - writing a large dynamic array to disk using stream

Tags: arrays, delphi, dynamic, tstream

In a Delphi program, I have a dynamic array with 4,000,000,001 cardinals.  I'm trying to write (and later read) it do a drive.  I used the following:

```
const Billion = 1000000000;

stream := tFileStream.Create( 'f:\data\BigList.data', fmCreate);
stream.WriteBuffer( Pointer( BigArray)^, (4 * billion + 1) * SizeOf( cardinal));
stream.free;
```

It bombed out with: ...raised exception class EWriteError with message 'Stream write error'.

The size of the file it wrote is only 3,042,089KB.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a limit to the size that can be written at once (about 3GB)?

Comment: Dumb questions:  1.  Did you have enough disk space (4bn * cardinals will require 16Gb).  2. What's the file system of the disk you are writing to ?  Some file systems have file size limits (e.g. 4Gb per single file on FAT32).  3. If F: is a network drive, have you tried writing the file in smaller increments ?  4. Are you compiling to 32-bit or 64-bit ?  If 32-bit then you may be running into a problem addressing your BigArray (though the ~3Gb limit you appear to be reaching is a little unexpected, if that were the case).

Comment: Why are you calculating the number of bytes this way? You could just ask the array: `stream.WriteBuffer( Pointer(BigArray)^, Length(BigArray) * SizeOf(Cardinal));` on the other hand, the length of a dynamic array is expressed as an integer, so it can't even hold 4 billion cardinals to begin with.

Comment: 1. Yes, the drive has about 2TB free. 2. NTFS. 3. F is an internal HD. 4. 64-bit platform.

Comment: 1. Yes, the drive has about 2TB free. 2. NTFS. 3. F is an internal HD. 4. 64-bit platform.                                         
------------------
I'm calculating the size this way because (even though it is a dynamic array), it has a fixed size (and larger than a static array can be).  If a dynamic array can hold only 2^31 elements (I wish they would make Delphi fully 64-bit), then that could cause a problem. I checked the 3 billionth term and the 4 billionth term of the array, but it may be wrapping around without me knowing it.

Comment: var cc : cardinal;
    BigArray : array of cardinal;

    SetLength( BigArray, 4 * billion + 1);  

    for cc := 1 to 4 * billion do BigArray[ cc] := cc;

    cc := 200 * millionInt64;

    repeat
      writeln( cc:12, BigArray[ cc]:12);
      inc( cc, 200 * MillionInt64);
    until cc > 4 * billion;
  
gives correct output.
   200000000   200000000
...
  3800000000  3800000000
  4000000000  4000000000

Comment: Is there way to get a CR/LF in these messages?

Comment: Dynamic arrays can be sized to 2^63 in the 64 bit compiler, that's not your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Count` parameter of `WriteBuffer` is a 32 bit integer so you cannot pass the required value in that parameter. You will need to write the file with multiple separate calls to `WriteBuffer`, where each call passes a count that does not exceed this limit.

I suggest that you write it something like this.

```
var
  Count, Index, N: Int64;
.... 
Count := Length(BigArray);
Index := 0;
while Count > 0 do begin
  N := Min(Count, 8192);
  stream.WriteBuffer(BigArray[Index], N*SizeOf(BigArray[0]));
  inc(Index, N);
  dec(Count, N);
end;
```

An additional benefit is that you can readily display progress.

Comment: Well, it looks like the best thing to do is to do WriteBuffer in a loop and write < 2^31 bytes at the time, right?

Comment: Er, that's exactly what I said in this answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why 8196? Maybe it's 8192?

Comment: @Bozzy Yeah, not that it really matters of course, perhaps I should have picked a power of 10!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies.